# Calling object members in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have 2 objects which is bob and mary and i want to call their firstName and lastName values in a function with using an array but this code doesn't seem to work

```
var bob = {
    firstName: "Bob",
    lastName: "Jones",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 777-7777",
    email: "bob.jones@example.com"
};

var mary = {
    firstName: "Mary",
    lastName: "Johnson",
    phoneNumber: "(650) 888-8888",
    email: "mary.johnson@example.com"
};

var contacts = [bob, mary];


var printPerson = function(person) {
    console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
}

printPerson(contacts[0]);
printPerson(contacts[1]);
```

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your function `this` refers to the `window` object.

Use the object that is passed to the function as parameter.

Use `person.firstName` and `person.lastName` to get the names from the respective object.

```
var printPerson = function(person) {
    console.log(person.firstName + " " + person.lastName);
    //          ^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access firstName and lastName attributes from person parameter. So, your code must be:

```
var printPerson = function(person){
    console.log(**person**.firstName + " " + **person**.lastName);   
}
```